# Super init in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to convert code objective c to swift. I convert many of them but I have a problem in code init part.

How can I fix my 3 error. It is looking easy to fix them deleting if statement. But for this problem I could not find real solution. 
Deleting if statement It can cause the problem?

My codes:

```
My objective c code:

-(id)init
{
    self = [super init]; 
    if (self) // In swift I can delete this statement to solve my problem. Is it causing the problem?
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}
-(id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) //Also I can delete this if to solve the error but I am not sure is it the best way
    {
        [self commonInit];
    }
    return self;
}


-(void)commonInit
{
    self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    self.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    _textView = [[UITextView alloc] init];

    _timeLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    _statusIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] init];

    [self.contentView addSubview:_timeLabel];
    [self.contentView addSubview:_statusIcon];

}
```

And my swift code:

```
init() {

        super.init()  //Gives Error: Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell'

        if self != nil { //Value of type 'MessageCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

            self.commonInit()
        }
    }

    //Added this init because Xcode gives error if not add
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }


    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){

        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        if self != nil { //Error: Value of type 'MessageCell' can never be nil, comparison isn't allowed

          self.commonInit()
        }

    }

 func commonInit() {

        //set values

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        self.selectionStyle = .None
        self.accessoryType = .None

        self.timeLabel = UILabel()
        self.statusIcon = UIImageView()

        self.contentView.addSubview(timeLabel)
        self.contentView.addSubview(statusIcon)        
    }
```

Comment: What is your interpretation of the error messages?

Comment: @Wain Added the errors inside the code. it says Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'UITableViewCell' in init part. And the other error is below the this error

Comment: I saw that, I'm asking what you think they mean

Comment: Really I could not understand why it is giving error. This is my custom class and it has inherited from UITableViewCell. (class MyCell: UITableViewCell)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you go inside the sources of UITableViewCell, you will see:

```
public init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
```

There is no `init()`, that's why you are getting the *Must call a designated initializer* error; you are trying to call `NSObject`'s init method.
On a first pass, you could write something like this:

```
init() {
   super.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "example reuse id")
   self.commonInit()
}
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
   super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
   self.commonInit()
}
```

Note that there is no need to check if self is nil in the second initializer, as it is not failable - meaning you will always have a valid and fully initialized object.
But, seeing that there is now quite a bit of duplication, if you still want a default `init()` you can get rid of the commonInit all together:

```
convenience init() {
   self.init(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "example reuse id")
}
override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?){
   super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
   //you can initialize your object here, or call your commonInit
}
```

Mind that if you don't need default values, you can also get rid of the first `convenience init()` :)